# Qual é o problema no meu programa?

Tags: c, c++

Estou tentando entender melhor o funcionamento de ponteiros no C e no C++ e
para isso estou tentando fazer este pequeno programa de listas encadeadas (peguei o exemplo do livro "Estruturas de Dados" da editora Cengage Learning).
Não estou conseguindo entender o por quê do meu programa apresentar *LAST* diferente de *FIM*, sendo que os dois se referenciam ao mesmo valor.

help pls!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

typedef struct DataNodeHeader
{
    uintptr_t *inicio;
    uintptr_t *fim;
}DataNodeHeader;

typedef struct DataNode
{
    DataNodeHeader dnh;
    char data;
    int node_size;
    uintptr_t *next;
}DataNode;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    DataNode dn[5];

    const int def_size = (sizeof(dn) / sizeof(dn[0]) - 1); // TAMANHO FINAL DO DATANODE
    for (int i = 0; i <= def_size; i++)
    {
        dn[i].data = (char)i;
        dn[i].node_size = sizeof(dn[i]);
        dn[i].next = &dn[i + 1];

        if (i == 0)
        {
            dn->dnh.inicio = &dn[i];
            printf("FIRST: %p\n", &dn[i]);
        }

        printf("DATA:%d\n", dn[i].data);
        printf("NODE_SIZE: %d\n", dn[i].node_size);

        if (i != def_size)
            printf("NEXT:%p\n\n", dn[i].next);

        if(i == def_size)
        {
            dn->dnh.fim = &dn[i]; // dn[i].dnh.fim é atribuido com um ponteiro que aponta para &dn[i]
            printf("LAST:%p\n\n", &dn[i]);
        }
    }

    printf("INICIO:%p\n", &dn->dnh.inicio);
    printf("FIM:%p\n", &dn->dnh.fim);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
FIRST: 00D3FBB0
DATA : 0
NODE_SIZE : 20
NEXT : 00D3FBC4

DATA : 1
NODE_SIZE : 20
NEXT : 00D3FBD8

DATA : 2
NODE_SIZE : 20
NEXT : 00D3FBEC

DATA : 3
NODE_SIZE : 20
NEXT : 00D3FC00

DATA : 4
NODE_SIZE : 20
LAST : 00D3FC00 <--- LAST REFERENCIADO NO TEXTO

INICIO : 00D3FBB0
FIM : 00D3FBB4 <---  FIM REFERENCIADO NO TEXTO
```

Comment: Liga o máximo de warnings do teu compilador e toma atenção a esses warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    printf("INICIO:%p\n", &dn->dnh.inicio);
    printf("FIM:%p\n", &dn->dnh.fim);
```

Os valores impressos acima são os **endereços** de `dn->dnh.inicio` e `dn->dnh.fim`. Para imprimir o conteúdo (o valor do ponteiro) usa

```
    printf("INICIO:%p\n", (void*)dn->dnh.inicio);
    printf("FIM:%p\n", (void*)dn->dnh.fim);
```

Comment: Oi pmg, por curiosidade, esse cast é necessário?

Comment: Sim, @AnthonyAccioly, o cast é necessário. Vê o [Standard 7.21.6.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1): "... p: The argument **shall be a pointer to void**. ..." e [Standard 6.5.2p28](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p28): "... Pointers to other types need not have the same representation or alignment requirements." *(em principio, nos computadores actuais comuns, não há problema em deixar o cast de fora ...)*

Comment: Nossa! Nunca teria descoberto isso sozinho e no livro nada disso é citado. Obrigado! :)